# Can I display a file on a website while having it private in file manager?

Tags: html, wordpress, web-hosting, file-management

I am making a website on wordpress and I have a password protected section that I would like to display files on in an iframe or other embedded format. However I don't want the files to be accessed in a way that circumvents the password such as by using the link to it's location in the file manager like site.com/files/file.jpeg. However when I restrict read access then I can't display it on my site. Is there any way the files can be private on the server (i.e. not findable via a url) but still able to display on the webpage?